# Java: How to add Environment Variables to a JUnit Tests in Gradle

Tags: gradle

I've managed to get the test task to run my unit tests, but they fail because env properties I am using are not set, eg: `String base=System.getenv("TESTNG_BASE_PATH");`

So, I've done  something like:

```
tasks.withType(Test) {
   systemProperty 'TESTNG_BASE_PATH','long\\path\\to\env\var\value'   
}
```

But I still get the same exception from my code that the file is not found, so its obviously not the right way of doing this.

So how to do this, please?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you are getting via `System.getenv(...)` you'll need to set an environment variable. I've also included a command line flag for switching on/off standard streams

```
tasks.withType(Test) { 
    environment 'TESTNG_BASE_PATH','long\\path\\to\env\var\value'
    testLogging.showStandardStreams = Boolean.parseBoolean(findProperty('showStandardStreams'))
}
```

To run you could do

```
./gradlew check -PshowStandardStreams=true
```

Comment: I just tried that - still having the same exception thrown by my code :( So I think its not working, but what is compounding the diagnostics difficulty, is that something is intercepting my `System.out.println(e.getMessage());` and `printStackTrace` - because I simply dont see these outputted, only the console output is what test failed, what exception and in which line... thats it.

Comment: You can add `test { testLogging.showStandardStreams = true }` to show System.out and System.err in the console. See [here](https://docs.gradle.org/current/dsl/org.gradle.api.tasks.testing.logging.TestLoggingContainer.html#org.gradle.api.tasks.testing.logging.TestLoggingContainer:showStandardStreams)

Comment: Excellent! This has finally enabled me to figure out what the problem was. Could you please tell me if we could move the showStandardStreams setting to a command line argument to gradle, so that we can easily use it for debugging when there is a build issue from Jenkins, without committing file changes just to test.

Comment: See my updated answer. More info [here](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/build_environment.html#sec:gradle_properties_and_system_properties)

Comment: Thanks, that problem is solved, but I still have other errors saying something about ENV environment value not being set (a different one) - the best way for me to go forth is to debug while running from Gradle test task - is that possible? How?